# Scala generics with unknown number of types

Tags: scala

I have a scala function that should receive any number of `Iterable[T]`s of an unknown and different `T`s.

for example, this is a valid call

```
foo(Iterable(1, 2, 3), Iterable(" "))
```

and should be translated to something like

```
foo(arg1: Iterable[Int](1, 2, 3),
    arg2: Iterable[String](" "))
```

Note that the following does not work.

```
foo(args: Iterable[Any]*)
```

Because I need each iterable to be of one specific type.

Here's an example of how I want this to look:

```
foo[T*](arge: Iterable[T]*) = {
  args.foreach({
    case _: Iterable[Int] => ...
    case _: Iterable[String] => ...
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `HList` from Shapeless should most likely give you what you want. Searching for it will give plenty of articles.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "Because I need each iterable to be of one distinct type"? Do you mean that `foo(Iterable(1, 2, 3), Iterable(4, 5, 6))` should not compile because both iterables are of the same type? Also, what will you do with the iterables in foo's body? Because you'll certainly want to process them in some way, which means you'll need a way to do this processing without knowing in advance their exact type (which could be done through a type class). In short, please give more information so that a meaningful answer can be articulated.